# Access jest mocked module properties

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Right now I have such construction for mocking request. 
I want to test properties that are inside of `jest.mock`

```
import react from "react"

jest.mock("../../../api", () => ({
  useGetRequest: () => ({
    data: mockMyCards,
    isLoading: false,
})

it(() => {
render()
// how to test that useGetRequest had been called, how to access insides of jest.mock 
// expect(useGetRequest).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your mocked `useGetRequest` in `jest.fn()`. Something like:

```js
// Notice the function below
const mockedUseGetRequest = jest.fn(() => ({ 
  data: mockMyCards,
  isLoading: false,
}));

jest.mock('../../../api', () => ({
  useGetRequest: () => mockedUseGetRequest(),
}));

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  it('should call useGetRequest', () => {
    render(<YourComponent />);
    expect(mockedUseGetRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // Your other assertions...
  });
});
```